# Geolocation give wrong position?

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Well I have a problem with Geolocation, when the page is initialized I have “right” location, after I refresh the page there are different location, maybe 10 meters from first. After one more refresh I have a third location, etc.. I tested on this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation  , and again I don’t have a right position.

Answer (score 4):

Accuracy of geolocation depends on how does your geolocation is determined. It may change.
There are a variety of ways that your
device and the location service provider
calculate your position, and some are more
accurate than others. GPS is often the most
accurate.

You may like to know

**How the Geolocation API determines your location** -

**IP Address**
Location information based
on your IP address uses an
external database to map
the IP address to a physical
location. The advantage of this
approach is that it can work
anywhere; however, often
IP addresses are resolved to
locations such as your ISP’s
local office. Think of this
method as being reliable
to the city or sometimes
neighborhood level.

**GPS**
Global Positioning System,
supported by many newer mobile
devices, provides extremely
accurate location information based
on satellites. Location data may
include altitude, speed and heading
information. To use it, though, your
device has to be able to see the sky,
and it can take a long time to get a
location. GPS can also be hard on
your batteries.

**Cell Phone**
Cell phone triangulation
figures out your location
based on your distance from
one or more cell phone towers
(obviously the more towers, the
more accurate your location
will be). This method can be
fairly accurate and works indoors
(unlike GPS); it also can be much
quicker than GPS. Then again, if
you’re in the middle of nowhere
with only one cell tower, your
accuracy is going to suffer.

**WiFi**
WiFi positioning uses one or more
WiFi access points to triangulate
your location. This method
can be very accurate, works
indoors and is fast. Obviously
it requires you are somewhat
stationary (perhaps drinking a
venti iced tea at a coffee house).

Comment: The problem is that the geolocation works fine for 2 months, and in the last 20 days I have a problems with wrong location but the code is  same. I need to use geolocation, because I have web application. I wonder if there are some other solution different from geolocation, or If there are any solution for my problem.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I know all that, but I don't know how to limit gelocation to use only gps, it's that possible ?

Comment: you also get `accuracy` property in position, may be you can use it to know how accurate is coords

Comment: you can pass an `option` object to `getCurrentPosition`, which has `enableHighAccuracy` property. With the `enableHighAccuracy` option, you’re telling the API you need the most accurate location it can get, even if it is costly. Just keep in mind, using this option doesn’t guarantee the browser can give you a more accurate location.

Comment: Yes I'm using enableHighAccuracy property.But the result is the same. If you have a some device with  gps you can also test geolocation, refresh your page a couple of times, and you can see that the location is not the same. It's better to print out your latitude and longitude values and you can see the and you can see the changes. Only solution is if I have a wrong position a drag pointer to the right position and then I save, but that is not the best solution..

Comment: Most of the times, accuracy depends on users device. If I can know what exactly you want to do with this feature, I may help in a better way.

Comment: I would like to show position on google map and also get the address name with geocoder(Google Geocoder), but I need very high accuracy because can't store in database wrong address, interesting is that before 2 months I implement that and all works fine, but In the last 2 or 3 weeks I always get wrong address. It's not big difference, it's about 10 , 20 meters and most difference are 100m.

Comment: In that case, you already have mentioned the solution, show the coordinates on map and if not correct let user modify it. As far as I think this is the only solution.

Comment: Yep, I already implement that. User just modify pointer on map with drag and drop method, but it's not the best solution. Anyway thanks for your time. Regards !